# WSO2 Analytics - purge data repository

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I'm facing some data purging issues with the WSO2 Analytics. There's this folder on `${WSO2_HOME}/repository/data` that keeps growing and I'm not able to purge it through the WSO2 Analytics. Databases are being purged properly but this folder keeps growing and crashing the service as my server can't handle more data.

I've tried setting up as the [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Purging+Data) says. And I'm still having this issue.

Does somebody have any idea or can confirm that setting up the conf with the link above should resolve this issue?

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: I believe that setting the purging period helped for me

Comment: Thank you for your response @gusto2 

Did you schedule a global data purging? or per table?